# C# Destructor not calling after out of scope

Tags: c#, scope, destructor

I have problem with destructor after going out of scope(it is calling but after some time and need to make an action on form, for example change radio button), maybe there's mistake in my code.  Take a look:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            EventLogger.Print += delegate(string output)
            { if (!textBox1.IsDisposed) this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.AppendText(output + Environment.NewLine)), null); };
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestClass test = new TestClass();
        }
    }
    public static class EventLogger
    {
        public delegate void EventHandler(string output);
        public static event EventHandler Print;
        public static void AddLog(String TextEvent)
        {
            Print(TextEvent);
        }
    }
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
            EventLogger.AddLog("TestClass()");
        }
        ~TestClass()
        {
            EventLogger.AddLog("~TestClass()");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I d recommend you use IDisposable pattern rather than destructor. especially if you dont have a OS level handle. you shouldnt be using destructor.

Comment: Never rely upon the destructor.

Comment: on another note. do u even have a question. destructor is invoked at GC time and that s out of your control. you cant force GC to clean up as well. you dont even need any desctructor in your code anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right, because this isn't C++.  The finalizer (not destructor as in C++) is not guaranteed to be called immediately after an object has left its declaring scope, it is called when the GC decides to swoop in and clean up after you.

May I ask why you are using a finalizer to begin with?  Are you maintaining references to unmanaged resources which need to be deallocated as deterministically as possible (if so, read up on the IDisposable interface)?  The use cases for C# finalizers are few and far between, it's not common to implement them.

Comment: When I'm not using form application but console, everything in OK.

Comment: @user1112008 u dont need a destructor for your code. why do u think u need it?

Comment: I just needed to automate UI. Each class is contained in listview on form as text . When it's creating it's adding to listview from constructor, then going out of scope(destructor), it's removing from listview. Sorry for my english.

Comment: @user1112008 That is idiomatic in C++ using RAII, but the pattern isn't directly transferrable to C#. The closest you have in C# is the "using pattern", but you might want to look into architecturing things differently altogether. RAII is really a C++-specific pattern because of destructors.

Answer (score 4):

C# is not C++. [Destructors don't run synchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx).

There is no bugs in your code as is, but it looks like you may need to implement "IDisposable pattern" for your class to provide a way for caller to guaranty that some destruction of your object is executed synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

For those of us who are more comfortable with the C++ pattern it's useful to check out the docs for the IDisposable interface:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Unfortunately I've just tried it and it's not working as I'd like. I used an automatic object to save the current state of the GUI cursor, switch to the wait cursor and restore the original cursor as the object goes out of scope. The IDisposable interface does result in the cursor being restored but not immediately - so the Wait Cursor is showing for too long. Too bad because this is a very useful pattern.

Update: The C# try/finally pattern is comfortable enough after a while:

```
public void do_something_time_consuming()
{
   ShowBusyCursor cursor = new ShowBusyCursor();

   try
   {
      ...
      return;
   }
   finally
   {
      cursor.done();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The finalizer is not designed to be called immediately after going out of scope. It is called when the object is garbage-collected, which be may anywhere from milliseconds to days after going out of scope.

The finalizer is NOT meant for this kind of code. It is only for resource cleanup.

You can't force it to do something immediately after going out of scope, but you can tell it to immediately before going out of scope, with a `Close()` or similar method to signal that the object is done being used.

For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestClass test = new TestClass();
    // do stuff
    test.Close();
}
```

Note: You could implement `IDisposable`, as has been suggested, but this use doesn't exactly fit the intended use of `IDisposable`, so although it would work, it's a bit hackish.

Comment: yeah but the beauty of putting it in the destructor is that (in C++) it's called whenever the object goes out of scope.  meaning any time you return from the function, the destructor is called. which saves you having to call `test.Close()` before every return statement in your function.